# Error encountered in WCF REST POST method

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

I have created a WCF REST service with all CRUD operations. I am having problem in PUT and POST methods.

Also here is my interface code with all of the methods. [IEventService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e163g.png)

I am using this service in a UWP application. I have created a Helper method which is accessing the method from my WCF REST Service.

```
public static async void AddNewEvent()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59093/EventService.svc/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            Models.Event eventInfo = new Models.Event()
            {
                EventId = 8,
                Name = "C",
                ETime = DateTime.Now.Date,
                STime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(2),
                Cost = 980,
                Description = "REST.",
                Slots = 2
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventInfo);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("NewEvent", content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

As I try to use the PUT and POST method by passing the content in my Helper method, I get the code as follows:

[Error in My service.svc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c5ep.png)

I am sending data as we send in web api, but it is giving me error that object reference is not set to an instance of an object. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be sql error.Can you check what does eve variable contains?Specifically the description property of eve variable.

Comment: I am sending StringContent with my HttpClient's PostAsync() method, but the data is not being transmitted to eve variable. And it's null.

Comment: That is the reason you have null reference exception,you need to check your PostAsync() method.

Comment: How can I fix that? In a Web API, I used the same StringContent to send the data and it worked but here it is not working with WCF REST service. I am new to WCF REST service. Please help me with that.